# Struggling coding with buttons

Tags: encoding, arduino

Ive been really struggling recently with one problem.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to make one button trigger one sequence on an 8x8 display for 10 seconds and go off AND also have another button to make a different sequence for 10 seconds then go off and so on.

If anyone can help me please respond, it would be much appreciated :)

Here is the CODE:

```
    const int buttonPin = 3
int button = 0;
long now = 0;


setup(){

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

}

loop(){
  button = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if(button==HIGH){

  lc.setRow(0, 0, B00000000);
  lc.setRow(0, 1, B00011000);
  lc.setRow(0, 2, B00100100);
  lc.setRow(0, 3, B01011010);
  lc.setRow(0, 4, B10011001);
  lc.setRow(0, 5, B10000001);
  lc.setRow(0, 6, B11111111);
  lc.setRow(0, 7, B00000000);
  delay(110);

  now = millis();
 }
  delay(50);

  if(millis()>now + 10000){

  lc.setRow(0, 0, B00000000);
  lc.setRow(0, 1, B00000000);
  lc.setRow(0, 2, B00100100);
  lc.setRow(0, 3, B01011010);
  lc.setRow(0, 4, B10011001);
  lc.setRow(0, 5, B10000001);
  lc.setRow(0, 6, B11111111);
  lc.setRow(0, 7, B00000000);
  delay(110);
  }
}
```

Here is the help sheet i got from my tutor but i cant get my head around it:

[Help sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkOuL.jpg)

Thanks Matt

Comment: Do you have external pullup resistor?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `delay(50);`.  The arduino does not check the input pins during these 50 milliseconds, and it's likely when you are pressing a button.  You can either attach an interrupt function when the button is pressed (https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/).  Or you could try a looped delay like so:

```
unsigned int startTime = millis();
unsigned int currentTime = startTime;
while(currentTime - startTime >= 50) {
    // check button state
    currentTime = millis();
}
```

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StateChangeDetection

From the code you posted it appears you don't need `delay(50);` at all.

Comment: I am not familiar with `lc.setRow();`.  You could create a simple program to test the button input like so: 
`setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}
loop(){ Serial.println(digitalRead(buttonPin);}`

Comment: Is there a reason for the two `delay(110);` lines?  They don't seem necessary.

Comment: Your program also won't edit the display for 10 seconds, or until the button is pressed.  You could add a `lc.setRow()` in the setup function.

Comment: That all makes sense to me however i have not much undestanding of coding the arduino so i would need some guidance to help me with that.

Comment: Is your display turning on?  From what I understand about programing led displays, I think the codes (B00000000 for example) tell the arduino each light to turn on in a row.  Each digit in the number represents a led in a row.  B10000000 turns on the first light in the row, and turns the rest off.  B00000001 turns on the last light in the row and the rest off.  The 'b' before the number simply tells the compiler to treat the number as a binary number instead of an base 10 number like normal.

Comment: That i understand as i get get the image i want fine, but im stuggling how to command the image to stay on for a peiod of time using buttons.

Comment: -Jake Perret I tried this just to test but i cant figure out whats wrong with it: setup()
{ Serial.begin(9600);


pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); } 

loop()

  {Serial.printIn(digitalRead(buttonPin);}
}

Comment: Actually i have now finished the code related with using touch buttons to control an 8x8 display, i just coded it up as a digital read sequence and it was pretty easy after i figured out how to properly code it :)

Comment: Here is the code:  include <LedControl.h>
LedControl lc=LedControl(2,1,0);
unsigned long frameTime=2;  // make it 2 to 500
unsigned long rowDelay=500;   // make it 0 to 500
int Button = 4;
int pushButton = 3;
int ButtonValue = 0;


void setup() {
    pinMode(Button, INPUT);
    pinMode(pushButton, INPUT);

  lc.shutdown(0,false);
  /* Set the brightness to a medium values */
  lc.setIntensity(0,12);
  /* and clear the display */
  lc.clearDisplay(10000);
}